# Rebuild index to a new tablespace, seems to be not working for a pariticular index

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have an index in table_spae_1.
I used the following command to move to table_space_2

```
alter index my_table_index rebuild tablespace table_space_2 online parallel 63 nologging; 
alter index my_table_index noparallel;
alter index my_table_index logging;
```

But even after executing this the index is still showing to be in table_space_1. (I tried with multiple indexes and all others worked).

The table which contains this index is a very large table(more than 100million records).

What could be the reason? 
   How can I debug?

Comment: How do you check the tablespace? Is it a partitionized index/table?

Comment: it is an index table. Not a partitioned one.

Comment: Do you mean " Index-Organized Table"?

Comment: I dropped the index and recreated. (Is that the only solution?)

Comment: Yes. It is an index organized table

Comment: Check this one [Moving (Rebuilding) Index-Organized Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm#ADMIN11696)